# How to check if SQL Server table has rows and return table name as column name and value true or false

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create a view which will query a few specified tables and return a view table with one row. Table must be formed with column with table names and one row must be returned with values True/False depending on the table have rows or not.

For example, I have four tables:

```
Medication / Patient / User / Appointment
```

I need to check them tables if they have rows or not and return a view table with one row and columns like that.

```
Medication | Patient | User | Appointment
True       | False   | False| True
```

Comment: This information is already in MS SQL system tables, why do you want to create another view?

Comment: See the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443704/query-to-list-number-of-records-in-each-table-in-a-database) for a query you can modify

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to do this, if it is just these 4 tables you can use this:

```
select
(select Case When (select COUNT(*) FROM Medication) > 0 then 'true' else 'false' end) as Medication,
(select Case When (select COUNT(*) FROM Patient) > 0 then 'true' else 'false' end) as Patient,
(select Case When (select COUNT(*) FROM Appointment) > 0 then 'true' else 'false' end) as Appointment
```