# query for counting various stuff in all tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a database with a bunch of tables.

I want to build a query, that lists all the tables in the database, and then do various counts in those tables.

For example count "How many rows that has `'D'` as country" etc.

I have figured out to do a `SELECT name FROM db.sys.tables` to get all the tables, just can't wrap my head around the situation that I want to do counts on the tables also.

Its the same count I want to do in all tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query to list number of records in each table in a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443704/query-to-list-number-of-records-in-each-table-in-a-database)

Comment: Not excactly, it just count the rows from all the tables, I want to set up my own counts, like how many rows with a value of DK and more.

Comment: Wouldn't you just do a `Select Count(*) from... WHERE...` at that point?

Comment: Because there is 100 tables - So I want to do it in one query, instead of creating the count for each and every one of the tables.

Comment: "How many rows that has `DK` as country". what if that `country` column is not present in all the tables or does not have the same type?

Comment: Then I should reconstruct the database and tables;) The data is there and it is perfekt - just need the query to query it;)

Comment: what version of SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the undocumented system procedure `sp_msforeachtable` like this

```
DECLARE @results TABLE(tbl VARCHAR(100),countresult INT);

INSERT INTO @results
EXEC sp_msforeachtable @command1 = 'SELECT ''?'',Count(*) FROM ? /* Add your WHERE clause here*/',@replacechar = '?'

SELECT * FROM @results
```

You can read more about it [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm) and [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2007/10/23/60383.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - that works pretty good for what I am making.