# Filtering a SELECT statement based on row data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add a `WHERE` clause to a `SELECT` statement that checks to see if there is data in the table or if it was a 0-row table.

Basically, I'm trying to get this to work but obviously `tables.NAME` isn't a valid object.

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM   sys.tables 
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM   tables.NAME) <> 0
```

I don't want to have to create a temp table, declare a cursor and checking a value row by row, but I'm having a hard time thinking a bout how to do this otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cursor is a suitable solution to this problem. You can't dynamically interpret a column from one table as a table name and simultaneously select from that table to see if it's empty like you're attempting to do. In fact you can't even select from a dynamic table without using dynamic SQL. See the documentation for [FROM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx). You can either iterate over each table and check each, or you can [query system tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443704/query-to-list-number-of-records-in-each-table-in-a-database) that hold storage statistics to see if tables are empty.