# SQLDeveloper: Finding the total amount of rows within a database?

Tags: sql, database, row

Within my database I would like to know the *total amount of rows*.

I am able to find out the amount of rows in a certain table in my database with this query:

```
select count (*) From TABLE_NAME;
```

However, is there a more *efficient* way, rather than repeating this for every table?

Comment: this question may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221555/how-to-fetch-the-row-count-for-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database

Comment: you can use rownum and order by desc and take the first answer

Comment: Can you please give an example of this? Thanks Im very new to DB work?

Comment: Read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443704/query-to-list-number-of-records-in-each-table-in-a-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `pl/sql block` to know the total no of rows in all tables.

```
DECLARE  
   t_name VARCHAR2(100);  
   total_rows NUMBER;  
   t_count NUMBER;  
BEGIN  
  total_rows := 0;  
  t_count := 0;  

  FOR rec IN (SELECT table_name FROM user_tables)  
  LOOP  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(1) from '||rec.table_name  
    INTO t_count;  

    total_rows := total_rows + t_count;  
  END LOOP;  

  dbms_output.put_line('Total no of Rows: '||total_rows);  
EXCEPTION  
  WHEN OTHERS THEN  
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);  
END;
```