# Microsoft Dynamics 365 - get metadata

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there any mysql query available to get all the table names from Microsoft Dynamics 365 online.

I wanted to get all the table names are row count for each table in a single query.I tried union and union all but I think it is not working.
This is the first time I am working with MSD online.
Is it possible to do this using mysql query?

Comment: Are you sure you mean `mysql`? And not `tsql` or `sql`? Dynamics doesnt use `mysql`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query to list number of records in each table in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443704/query-to-list-number-of-records-in-each-table-in-a-database)

Comment: Hey James, thanks for your response , yes I wanted to use mysql. I am using Matillion, I had a discussion with their support team as well, so it is possible but not directly using Matillion but using JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, first of all, dynamics 365 online doesn't expose the database, in fact, only the Microsoft premier support team can scan it for performances issues or error messages, some of what you want to get is possible, but requires multiple instructions

SDK/WebAPI

You can get the metadata information using .NET SDK instruction ([RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg327609(v%3Dcrm.8))) or querying the WebAPI directly (in Browser or Non-microsoft languaje, this requires previous [register of your app in the Azure-AD of the instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/walkthrough-register-dynamics-365-app-azure-active-directory))

If you are working with MS Dyn Onpremise and you have access to the database, you should use the set of views with the "Filtered" Prefix, you could get the Metadata consulting the [information_schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and executing the count statement for each of them.

Hope it Helps

Regards