# Return number of rows from tables given the schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to return the number of records present in the individual tables from the database given the scheme in `TSQL`

Example: Schema=ABC, Tables = ABC.T1, ABC.T2, ABC.T3

Output of the query:

```
No of records  Table
 10             T1
 5              T2
 36             T3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need a transactionally consistent row count, you could query the DMVs. This will be much faster than `SELECT COUNT(*)` for large tables:

```
SELECT t.name, SUM(p.rows) AS row_count
FROM sys.tables AS t
JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.object_id = t.object_id AND p.index_id IN(0,1)
WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id) = N'ABC'
GROUP BY t.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `union all` :

```
select count(*) as [# of records], 't1' as [Table]
from abc.t1
union all
select count(*), 't2'
from abc.t2
union all
select count(*), 't3'
from abc.t3;
```

Comment: If I know only the Schema and do not know the number of tables that belong to that schema. In the example I specified 3 but what if its n?

Comment: @Gita. . . This would reflect your actual requirement --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443704/query-to-list-number-of-records-in-each-table-in-a-database

Comment: Thanks a ton! Got the solution