# Find number of rows of each column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote this short script which finds a specific column name in a SQL Server database:

```
SELECT
    sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,
    tables.name AS TableName
FROM
    sys.columns
JOIN 
    sys.tables ON sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
WHERE
    sys.columns.name LIKE '%ColumnName%'
```

I want to add another resulting column where number of rows of each column.

Comment: @debugging XD Do you mean distinct values or number of rows? Because the number of rows per column per table is the number of rows of that table.

Comment: @SNR number of rows of that table

Comment: @SNR Given a single column name, he wants the script to report back which table has that column, and how many rows it has. (Edit: since he's using LIKE I guess he wants partial matches in the report too.)

Comment: @debuggingXD, Bampfer Thanks, it seems that sys.partitions view has the number of rows per partition. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443704/query-to-list-number-of-records-in-each-table-in-a-database

Comment: @SNR Ture, this is what I wanted in the resulting rows column. I tried this one, but it gives the column rows for all tables. I am just searching for a ColumnName then I need how many rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there aren't any partitioned table:

```
USE [SpecificDatabank]
SELECT
  sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,
  sys.tables.name AS TableName,
  sys.partitions.rows AS [Rows]
FROM
  sys.columns
JOIN sys.tables ON
  sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
JOIN sys.partitions ON
  sys.tables.object_id = sys.partitions.object_id and sys.partitions.index_id in (0,1)
WHERE
  sys.columns.name LIKE '%ColumnName%'
```

Comment: Note that sys.partitions.rows is approximate. But for many purposes this would be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,
  tables.name AS TableName, Totals.Total

FROM
  sys.columns
JOIN sys.tables ON
  sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id 
  JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) total, sys.columns.name FROM
  sys.columns
JOIN sys.tables ON
  sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
  GROUP BY sys.columns.name
    ) Totals
    on Totals.name = sys.columns.name
WHERE
  sys.columns.name LIKE '%ColumnName%'
```

This returns the number of times a column exists across all of the tables

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I wanted. I wanted to get the number of (count of) rows in that ColumnName (without Null rows)