Perform a row count of each table in my list of tables
I have my query here to find the list of tables that don't have a primary key:
select schema_name(tab.schema_id) as [schema_name], 
    tab.[name] as table_name
from sys.tables tab
    left outer join sys.indexes pk
        on tab.object_id = pk.object_id 
        and pk.is_primary_key = 1
where pk.object_id is null
order by schema_name(tab.schema_id),
    tab.[name]

It comes back with a list of tables fine, but how do I do a row count of the number of records of each table in that list.

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443704/query-to-list-number-of-records-in-each-table-in-a-database

Dyamic SQL, or paste your list of tables into excel and build your queries using concatenation.  Crude, but it works.

Row counts are kept in sys.partitions
select schema_name(tab.schema_id) as [schema_name], 
    tab.[name] as table_name, SUM(P.[rows]) as [number of records] 
from sys.tables tab
    left outer join sys.indexes pk
        on tab.object_id = pk.object_id 
        and pk.is_primary_key = 1
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON tab.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID  AND p.index_id IN (0,1)
where pk.object_id is null
GROUP BY tab.schema_id,tab.[name]
order by schema_name(tab.schema_id),
    tab.[name]


@Martin Smith Thanks. Query updated.

ohw wow this worked perfectly thank you!

The documentation says Indicates the approximate number of rows in this partition.

@BartMcEndree Could you please decide if you want to capitalize SQL key words in your queries or not? I think answers here should have a minimal quality of code and not contain such a horrible mix of upper and lower case. Thanks.

@Jonas Metzler I agree. I always use upper case but the original query was lower.  In this case I think it helps to show Forgottenluv which lines I added.

A solution could be :
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = N'';
WITH 
T0 AS
(
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
EXCEPT
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
)
SELECT @SQL = @SQL +
       N'SELECT ''' + TABLE_SCHEMA + ''' AS TABLE_SCHEMA, ''' 
                  + TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TABLE_NAME, '
                  + N'COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT FROM '
                  + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' 
                  + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) 
                  + ' UNION ALL ' 
FROM   T0;
SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 10);
EXEC (@SQL);

Better use INFORMATION_SCHEM view, rather than sys views. They are more portable an simpliest
The result will give you the real number of row of each table that d'ont have primary key.
